# How to add span class caret inside anchor in cakephp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, drop-down-menu, anchor, caret

I have a dropdown navigation bar , built in bootstrap 3. The anchor tag in plain HTML is :

```
<a href="#" 
class="dropdown-toggle" 
data-toggle="dropdown"
data-hover="dropdown" 
data-delay="1000">
    Destinations <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

In cakephp, I have written as :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Destinations',
'#',
array(
       'class' => 'dropdown-toggle', 
        'data-delay' => '1000', 
        'data-hover' => 'dropdown'
     )
); ?>
```

I want to know where should I add the `<span class="caret"></span>` to the above so that the caret appears near the link ?

NB: I am using `CakePHP 2.6.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, as below:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Destinations<span class="caret"></span>','#',array('class' => 'dropdown-toggle', 'data-delay' => '1000', 'data-hover' => 'dropdown', 'escape' => false)); ?>
```

NB : don't forget to use `'escape' => false` to the array

Answer (score 0):

> You should try this

First

```
<?php  echo $this->Html->link("Destinations". $this->Html->tag('span', '', array('class' => 'caret')),array('controller' => 'ContrllerName', 'action' => 'ActionName'),array('class' => '', 'escape' => false)
            );
?>
```

Second

```
<?php    
     echo $this->Html->link('Destinations<span class="caret"></span>','#',
        array('class' => 'dropdown-toggle', 
            'data-delay' => '1000', 
            'data-hover' => 'dropdown',
             'escape' => false)
        );
     ?>
```

Setting escape to false will also disable escaping of attributes of the link